# unicornを通じて、railsの投稿アプリをデプロイしようとするとbundler: failed to load command: unicorn_railsが起きる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws

現在、railsで投稿アプリを作成し、AWSでデプロイしようとしたのですが、以下のコマンドで rails を起動させようとするとエラーが表示される状態です。

**実行したコマンド:**

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

エラー文を確認すると画像のような状態なのですが、ローカルでは問題なく動いており、gemに問題があると考えているのですがどこに変更を加えるべきなのかがわかりかねる状態です。
どこに問題があるのか分かるかたがいらっしゃれば教えていただきたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

同様のエラーが発生されている方がいましたのでリンクを掲載しておきます。

[unicornを再起動するとエラー【uninitialized constant Users (NameError)】 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/rockguitar67/items/55cffef50360a56b2794)

こちらは`unicorn rails uninitialized constant`でgoogle検索したらヒットしました。
エラー発生時はとりあえずエラーメッセージとコマンド名などで検索してみるといいかもしれません。

Comment: config.eager_load = falseで解決しました、ありがとうございました